# How to save streaming video to a separate file using python-vlc library?

Tags: python, vlc

There is a streaming stream played through vlc, the video is output, it is necessary to record from the moment the video is played and write it to a file at the end of the session. I read that you need to use --sout to save, but I did not find examples of how to implement it. If someone came across, then I will be glad to see an example of a working code, I am still new to python))

```
import vlc
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x400+0+0')
window.title("CH1")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

frame = Frame(window, width=200, height=20)
frame.pack()

display = Frame(frame)
display.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()

Media = Instance.media_new('rtsp://admin:12345678@192.168.0.90:554/live?pf=11&pt=tcp','--sout=C:\Python_Projects:stream.mp4')

player.set_xwindow(display.winfo_id())
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It was possible to save the video stream to a file, but every time it is launched, the video is resaved in this file. And how can I implement a method so that if there is a file with the same name, for example, stream.avi, it sees and creates a file with the name stream1.avi

Comment: Media = Instance.media_new('rtsp://...')

Comment: Media.add_option('sout=#duplicate{dst=file{dst=stream.avi},dst=display}')